# How to create a graph connecting predecessors and successors in time from a timeseries table in PostgreSQL 10?

Tags: postgresql, graph

I have the following table:

```
╔════╦═══════════╦═════════════════════╦═══════╗
║ id ║ sensor_id ║        time         ║ value ║
╠════╬═══════════╬═════════════════════╬═══════╣
║  1 ║         1 ║ 2018-01-01 00:00:01 ║     1 ║
║  2 ║         1 ║ 2018-01-01 00:00:02 ║     2 ║
║  3 ║         1 ║ 2018-01-01 00:00:03 ║     3 ║
║  4 ║         1 ║ 2018-01-01 00:00:03 ║     4 ║
║  5 ║         1 ║ 2018-01-01 00:00:04 ║     3 ║
║  6 ║         2 ║ 2018-01-01 00:00:01 ║     1 ║
║  7 ║         2 ║ 2018-01-01 00:00:01 ║     2 ║
║  8 ║         2 ║ 2018-01-01 00:00:02 ║     3 ║
║  9 ║         2 ║ 2018-01-01 00:00:03 ║     4 ║
║ 10 ║         2 ║ 2018-01-01 00:00:04 ║     5 ║
╚════╩═══════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════╝

CREATE TABLE sensor_time_series
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    "time" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    sensor_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    value NUMERIC NOT NULL,
);
```

**It's a timeseries table that represents the value of a sensor at a specific time**. Yes, I know it's strange that "time" is not unique inside each "sensor_id", that's an error from the dataset.

What I want is to make a new table/view with a graph structure, connecting each "sensor_id" sample to its successor in "time". The table should look something like this:

```
╔════════════╦══════════════╗
║ current_id ║ successor_id ║
╠════════════╬══════════════╣
║          1 ║           2  ║
║          2 ║           3  ║
║          2 ║           4  ║
║          3 ║           5  ║
║          4 ║           5  ║
║          6 ║           8  ║
║          7 ║           8  ║
║          8 ║           9  ║
║          9 ║          10  ║
╚════════════╩══════════════╝

CREATE TABLE sensor_time_series_graph
(
    current_id INTEGER,
    successor_id INTEGER,
    FOREIGN KEY (current_id) REFERENCES sensor_time_series(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (successor_id) REFERENCES sensor_time_series(id)
);
```

Both columns (current_id and successor_id) FOREIGN KEY's **id** from the first table
How can I create something like this in PostgreSQL 10?

I was looking into PostgreSQL window functions and I think they can help me, but did not realized how yet.

Comment: I can't see a way to do this using window functions without stacking CTEs two deep. - something like `lag(id,count-rank+1),id`  still should execute faster than a self join.

Comment: @Jasen One "parent" may produce a list of records with different "childs". So You NEED at least one self-join.

Comment: @Jasen One source record cannot produce two output records. Ever when window function is used.

Comment: ah yeah, now I see,  sensor 1 has duplicated values in both columns.

Comment: @Akina that's a very intresting statement about input/output of records, that helps a lot in understanding your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id
     , t2.id
FROM sensor_time_series t1
INNER JOIN sensor_time_series t2 ON  t1.sensor_id = t2.sensor_id 
                                 AND t1."time" < t2."time"
LEFT JOIN sensor_time_series t3 ON  t1.sensor_id = t3.sensor_id 
                                AND t1."time" < t3."time" 
                                AND t3."time" < t2."time"
WHERE t3.id IS NULL;
```

or (thanks to [Lennart](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/39278/lennart) for the [idea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/209180/150107))

```
SELECT t1.id
     , t2.id
FROM ( SELECT id
            , sensor_id
            , lead("time") over(partition by sensor_id order by time) AS leading
       FROM sensor_time_series ) t1
INNER JOIN sensor_time_series t2 ON  t1.sensor_id = t2.sensor_id 
                                 AND t1.id != t2.id
WHERE t2."time" = t1.leading;
```

In the last query the join/where conditions can be freely moved between those sections for the best visibility.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7a58368fa53d016712f6fd69d32ac2a3)

Answer (score 2):

If sensor_id and time where unique you could have used the window function lead:

```
select id, lead(id) over(partition by sensor_id order by time) as successor_id 
from sensor_time_series;
```

but since there can be several successors (if you have several consecutive multiple measurements the result will grow fast), you will need some kind of self-JOIN. This is a slight variation from [Akina's](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina) solution, using a `NOT EXISTS` predicate instead of a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id as successor_id
FROM sensor_time_series t1
JOIN sensor_time_series t2 
    ON t2.sensor_id = t1.sensor_id 
   AND t2.time > t1.time
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM sensor_time_series t3
    WHERE t1.sensor_id = t3.sensor_id
      AND t3.time < t2.time 
      AND t3.time > t1.time
)
```

If you want to include observations that don't have a successor, you can use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.id, t2.id as successor_id
FROM sensor_time_series t1
LEFT JOIN sensor_time_series t2 
    ON t2.sensor_id = t1.sensor_id 
   AND t2.time > t1.time
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM sensor_time_series t3
    WHERE t1.sensor_id = t3.sensor_id
      AND t3.time < t2.time 
      AND t3.time > t1.time
)
```

Another option is to use `dense_rank()` to determine the successors. It is convenient to use a CTE:

```
with t(id,sensor_id,rnk) as (
    select id, sensor_id
         , dense_rank() over (partition by sensor_id order by time) as rnk
    from sensor_time_series
)
select t1.id, t2.id
from t as t1
join t as t2
    on t1.sensor_id = t2.sensor_id
   and t2.rnk = t1.rnk+1;
```

Use `LEFT JOIN` between t1 and t2 if you want to include observations without successors.

Comment: Do you happen to know if your second query is faster than @Akina first query considering there is a btree index in (sensor_id, time)?

Comment: Dont know out of the box, compare the plans and execution time for a representative amount of data